# Create a GUI for a maze in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, graph, swt

I need to create a maze in Java where each time (i.e. every time I run the program ) a different maze would be made . 
The program consists of 3 levels : beginner (25 rooms) , advanced (40 rooms) and expert (60 rooms) , with players (up to 20 players) and treasures , where each player must get at least one treasure .

I've made the logic side of the maze , meaning , I've written the maze algorithm where 
each time the program randomly get a dot in the (x,y) plane and adds it to a graph - G=(V,E) -  where the vertices are the `rooms` , and the edges are `connectors` (Door/Wall) .

Now my problem , is that I need to represent the maze using GUI , so I've attached the SWT from the Eclipse's site to my program , but I do not know how to use the GUI to describe the maze/graph .

At first, I want to present to the user the maze before that game begins , meaning is , after creating the maze , before the players hit the road .

Can you please give me a hint where or how to start ?

the relevant classes are :

```
public class Room {



    private ArrayList<Connector> connectors;
    private int x;    // x coordinate of the room 
    private int y;    // y coordinate of the room 


    // constructor  

    Room(int xCoordinate,int yCoordinate)
    {
        //this.connectors = new HashMap<String,Connector>();
        this.connectors = new ArrayList<Connector>();
        this.x = xCoordinate;
        this.y = yCoordinate;
    }

    Room()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }


    public void addConnector(Connector connector)

    {
        this.connectors.add(connector);
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */

    public int getXcoordinate() 
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getYcoordinate()
    {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setXcoordinate(int newX)
    {
        this.x = newX;
    }

    public void setYcoordinate(int newY)
    {
        this.y = newY;
    }



}




package model;

public class Door extends Connector {


    // holds private Room[] rooms = new Room[2];

    Door(Room room1,Room room2) 
    {
        super(room1,room2);

    }

    public Room getNextRoom(Room room) 
    {
        if(this.rooms[0].equals(room))
        {
            return this.rooms[1];
        }
        return this.rooms[0];
    }


}


public abstract class Connector {


    protected Room[] rooms = new Room[2];
    public abstract Room getNextRoom(Room room);

    public Connector(Room room1,Room room2)  // building a new connector that connects between two rooms s
    {
        rooms[0] = room1;
        rooms[1] = room2;
    }

    public Room getFirstRoom()
    {
        return this.rooms[0];
    }

    public Room getSecondRoom()
    {
        return this.rooms[1];
    }



}
```

Regards,Ron

Comment: It depends how advanced a GUI you want. You can potentially draw this in the console window.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to plot a collection of points on to a UI?  If so, do you need to do this in SWT, or is Swing also an option?  Also, does the UI need to be interactive, or are you only displaying the "image" of the maze?

Comment: @ziesemer :Only using SWT , from my understanding (at least that's what the TA said) SWT would do the job. Do I need anything beside that  ?

Comment: @Doomsknight: you think it would be that simple ? I've tried to think of a way to draw it simply in the console , but it seems a little to complicated . Please notice that I don't(!!) use a grid NxN ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html .  You can draw lines, points, or any other geometry that you would need.